# Best method to Merge two Datasets (Maybe if function?)

Tags: r

I have two data sets I am working with. Datasets TestA and Test B (Below is how to make them in R)

```
Instructor <- c('Mr.A','Mr.A','Mr.B', 'Mr.C', 'Mr.D')
Class <- c('French','French','English', 'Math', 'Geometry')
Section <- c('1','2','3','5','5')
Time <- c('9:00-10:00','10:00-11:00','9:00-10:00','9:00-10:00','10:00-11:00')
Date <- c('MWF','MWF','TR','TR','MWF')
Enrollment <- c('30','40','24','29','40')

TestA <- data.frame(Instructor,Class,Section,Time,Date,Enrollment)

rm(Instructor,Class,Section,Time,Date,Enrollment)

Student <- c("Frances","Cass","Fern","Pat","Peter","Kory","Cole")
ID <- c('123','121','101','151','456','789','314')
Instructor <- c('','','','','','','')
Time <- c('','','','','','','')
Date <- c('','','','','','','')
Enrollment <- c('','','','','','','')
Class <- c('French','French','French','French','English', 'Math', 'Geometry')
Section <- c('1','1','2','2','3','5','5')


TestB <- data.frame(Student, ID, Instructor, Class, Section, Time, Date, Enrollment)

rm(Instructor,Class,Section,Time,Date,Enrollment,ID,Student)
```

I would like to merge both datasets (If possible, without using merge() ) So that All the columns of Test A are filled with the information provided by TestB and it should be added depending on the Class and Section.

I tried using merge(TestA, TestB, by=c('Class','Section'), all.x=TRUE) but it adds observations to the original TestA. This is just a test but in the datasets I am using there are hundreds of observations. It worked when I did it with these smaller frames but something is happening to the bigger set. That's why I'd like to know if there is a merge alternative.

Any ideas on how to do this?

The output should look like this

```
Class   Section Instructor  Time          Date   Enrollment Student ID
English  3      Mr.B    9:00-10:00  TR      24      Peter   456
French   1      Mr.A    9:00-10:00  MWF     30      Frances 123
French   1      Mr.A    9:00-10:00  MWF 30  Cass    121
French   2      Mr.A    10:00-11:00 MWF 40  Fern    101
French   2      Mr.A    10:00-11:00 MWF 40  Pat 151
Geometry 5      Mr.D    10:00-11:00 MWF 40  Cole    314
Math     5      Mr.C    9:00-10:00  TR  29  Kory    789
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're expecting the output to be?

Comment: Are you wanting to only merge a specific set of columns from `TestB`, like `merge(TestA, TestB[, c("Class","Section","ID")], by = c("Class", "Section"), all.x  = T)` ?

Comment: In this case all columns of TestB are in TestA so I'd like all of them to merge but merging them by class and section

Comment: I added what the output should be @SymbolixAU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was once a big fan of `merge()` until I learned about `dplyr`'s `join` functions.

Try this instead:

```
library(dplyr)

TestA %>%
    left_join(TestB, by = c("Class", "Section")) %>% #Here, you're joining by just the "Class" and "Section" columns of TestA and TestB
    select(Class, 
           Section, 
           Instructor = Instructor.x, 
           Time = Time.x, 
           Date = Date.x, 
           Enrollment = Enrollment.x, 
           Student, 
           ID) %>%
    arrange(Class, Section) #Added to match your output.
```

The `select` statement is keeping only those columns that are specifically named and, in some cases, renaming them.

Output:

```
     Class Section Instructor        Time Date Enrollment Student  ID
1  English       3       Mr.B  9:00-10:00   TR         24   Peter 456
2   French       1       Mr.A  9:00-10:00  MWF         30 Frances 123
3   French       1       Mr.A  9:00-10:00  MWF         30    Cass 121
4   French       2       Mr.A 10:00-11:00  MWF         40    Fern 101
5   French       2       Mr.A 10:00-11:00  MWF         40     Pat 151
6 Geometry       5       Mr.D 10:00-11:00  MWF         40    Cole 314
7     Math       5       Mr.C  9:00-10:00   TR         29    Kory 789
```

Comment: @LordVoldemort - while this is correct (+1), it seems more convoluted than the solution in my comment: `merge(TestA, TestB[, c("Class","Section","ID", "Student")], by = c("Class", "Section"), all.x = T)`

Comment: @SymbolixAU No doubt your solution is much simpler, but the OP asked how to merge both data sets "without using `merge()`."

Answer (score 2):

The key is to drop the empty but duplicate columns from `TestB` *before* merging / joining as shown by [SymbolixAU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684951/best-method-to-merge-two-datasets-maybe-if-function/47700689#comment82370860_47700689).

Here is an implementation in `data.table` syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(TestB)[, .(Student, ID, Class, Section)][setDT(TestA), on = .(Class, Section)]

   Student  ID    Class Section Instructor        Time Date Enrollment
1: Frances 123   French       1       Mr.A  9:00-10:00  MWF         30
2:    Cass 121   French       1       Mr.A  9:00-10:00  MWF         30
3:    Fern 101   French       2       Mr.A 10:00-11:00  MWF         40
4:     Pat 151   French       2       Mr.A 10:00-11:00  MWF         40
5:   Peter 456  English       3       Mr.B  9:00-10:00   TR         24
6:    Kory 789     Math       5       Mr.C  9:00-10:00   TR         29
7:    Cole 314 Geometry       5       Mr.D 10:00-11:00  MWF         40
```